# Why is my TH132 thermostat display going blank?

Tags: thermostat, floorheating

I have electric underfloor heating with a TH132 that is not working as the display keeps going blank and appearing to reset. Will replacing this with the TH232 resolve the problem?

Comment: Welcome. Please revise to add more information. Is this a new problem? What changes were made before it began? Why do you think a different model would help? What brand is a TH132?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @isherwood as to the last Q, the TH132 is a Honeywell/Aube product

Comment: Thanks, but I'm sure you realize I was asking on behalf of the community. That information belongs in the question.

Comment: Have you checked the voltage powering the unit?  Could be a bad connection.